# Cant delete files in dir with pattern

Tags: r

Sometimes I have to use R code to remove files in specific folders. To make sure i never remove something by accident I want to use `pattern` to make sure only desired files will be remove (so if I use wrong dir nothing will happen):

`file.remove(dir(path="D:/Folder/RestOfMyPath/",pattern="*_pattern.csv"))`

And i get:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
There were 28 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

And were i type `warnings()`:

```
1: In file.remove(dir(path = "D:/Folder/RestOfMyPath/",  ... :
  cannot remove file 'my_file1_pattern.csv', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I can see the files (my_file1_pattern.csv for example) are there. I can open them or delete manually. They all are generated by R but they are regular .csv files. The weirdest part is that this sometimes works but only as it feels like it. Sometimes i get `TRUE` instead `FALSE` and files are removed (rarely). But I cant figure out how to control it. I use R studio but same problem occurs in raw R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file.remove` is looking in the working directory for the files that you `dir`'ed in the other directory you supplied. `dir`'s output is just the file names.

Try

```
mydir <- "D:/Folder/RestOfMyPath/"
delfiles <- dir(path=mydir ,pattern="*_pattern.csv"))
file.remove(file.path(mydir, delfiles))
```

The "TRUE" instances are you blowing out (the wrong) files in the working directory that share the same name.